# Can anyone lift Mjolnir when it is disguised?

Tags: marvel, comics, thor-marvel, mjolnir

Clearly, very few people have shown the capability of being "***worthy***" to lift Mjolnir. However one question still arises.

According to Marvel wikia ([here](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Mjolnir)):

> ***Mjolnir can also transform its user into his civilian guises. When Thor was a civilian, the hammer most often became an old wooden cane.***

So, does the enchantment still hold when Mjolnir is disguised as

> a cane (***Comic-books***) or as an umbrella (in the ***Thor:Ragnarok***)?

Comment: Well, since in _Ragnarok_ the "umbrella" still makes the same sound as Mjolnir always has, and it's still capable of smashing stuff on its way back to Thor's hand, so I'd say the answer is probably no.

Comment: Even when it is not a cane people like Vision can lift it

Comment: @MetroBoomin But Vision's not a "person."

Comment: @Bob that is a very close minded attitude. Androids have fought long and hard for their "person" status. Even when they wear meat bodies like Vision, you people still look down on them. #androidsarepeopletoo

Comment: It might be funny, but it's also true.

Comment: @Bob: Star Trek TNG has a court case to rule on this in [The Measure of a Man](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Measure_Of_A_Man_(episode)). Even the opponent of android sentience argues the following criteria define a being as sentient: _Intelligence, self awareness, consciousness._ Vision has shown to have all three (he's even capable of emotions, which Data is not). I know I'm mixing story universes here, but I would recommend watching the TNG episode, it contains many well-reasoned arguments _pro and con_ android sentience.

Comment: @Flater OK, that's a good point.  What I was trying to say (but failed to be clear the first time) is that because Vision's existence and consciousness rely on the Mind stone, the rules for him might be different than for other, more "natural" beings.

Comment: @Bob: I see your point; but I think we need to factor in other circumstances. E.g. Tony Stark cannot move Mjölnir, but the SHIELD helicarrier _can_ move it. Earth's rotation and orbit is also no problem for Mjölnir's movement. It's been established that it can be transported within reason (yet a crane could not lift it in the first Thor movie). Due to the highly subjective nature of when it can and cannot be moved, it seems highly likely that Mjölnir itself (or an enchantment _on_ Mjölnir) is deciding this on a case by case basis, and it may have simply deemed Vision worthy.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to Thor Vol. 1 #138, the answer is that as a cane, there is no immovability enchantment on it:

[image: comic panels]

Comment: Now, the question is: What happens if someone breaks that cane?

Comment: @Bat Then Hela rises and Ragnarok begins.